# Doesn't get results after a while scraping (python)

Tags: python, web, block, screen-scraping

I'm trying to scrap a large database for a project of mine, however I find that after I scrap a relatively big amount of data, I stop receiving some of the xml information I'm interested in. I'm not sure if it's because the server is limiting my access or because it starts scraping too fast.

I put a "sleep" line between the scraping loops to overcome this, but as I try to reach more data it doesn't work anymore.
I guess this is a known problem in web scraping but I'm very new to this field so any suggestion will be very helpful.

Note: I tried 'request' with some free proxies but that didn't work either (still some data missing). I also checked the original website and it does have the data I seek.

Edit: It looks like most of that data I'm missing comes from specific attributes that don't load as fast as all other data. So I think I'm looking for a way to tell if this xml I'm looking for has loaded already.

I'm using lxml and requests.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have some code? Are you storing something in files? it could run out of memory, *for example*

Comment: @Evhz , I do have but it's more of a general question. Check my edit, I believe I know what causes this problem. And I'm writing after all computation is done, but so far it doesn't seem to frighthen my pc.